# How to do Jenkins windows node jdk upgrade and validate it

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-update

Our Jenkins controller is running on RedHat Linux. I am trying to update the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables in our jenkins windows node to point to JDK 11. Currently they are pointing to jdk1.8.0_181.

Now JDK 11 already installed in the node. I have also updated the jdk path under 'Manage Nodes' --> 'Windows Node'. But when I disconnect and start the node, under system information I could see the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables still pointing to older jdk version jdk1.8.0_181. We have rebooted the windows node server too. Still the system information points to old jdk version.

Can someone help me on the below queries?

1. How can we ensure system information reflects the change in jdk path?
2. Once it gets reflected, how can we validate our jenkins jobs consuming newly updated jdk version?

Comment: How are you connecting the nodes? SSH?